# Can Dragonblooded Characters Take Draconomicon Dragon Feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dragons

I'm making a Fireblood Dwarf, and I'm wondering if I, as a Dragonblooded creature, qualify for taking Dragon feats like Improved Speed and Rapidstrike?

Answer (score 2):

## No.

While the fireblood dwarf (*Dragon Magic* 7) has the subtype dragonblood (*DM* 4) (and, obviously, dwarf), the fireblood dwarf's *type* remains humanoid *not* dragon. Only creatures with the actual dragon type--not just the dragonblood subtype--meet the prerequisites of feats that have as a prerequisite the type dragon, like the feats Improved Speed (*Draconomicon* 71) and Rapidstrike (73).

Further, were a PC to qualify for such feats because of his type (e.g. when he advances a level the PC is the subject of the spell *essence of the dragon* [trans] (*Races of the Dragon* 112-3)) the player must still seek the DM's permission to take the feat if the feat's in the category monstrous (*Draconomicon* 66).

The dragonblood subtype, however, *does* allow a creature to take feats that have the dragonblood subtype as a prerequisite, such as some feats presented in *Dragon Magic* and *Races of the Dragon*.

Comment: Since when are monstrous feats special-permission-only? That’s a horrid rule.

Comment: @KRyan "The feats in [the Monstrous] category all require a 'monstrous' form or ability as a prerequisite. Monstrous forms and abilities are unavailable to normal humanoid or animal creatures, and can include extra or nonstandard appendages and supernatural or spell-like abilities. With the DM's permission, a player may be able to choose monstrous feats if his or her character has acquired unusual abilities through transformation or by advancing in a prestige class. See *Savage Species* for more examples of monstrous feats" (*Dr* 66). Yeah, the *Draconomicon* references *Savage Species.*

Answer (score 1):

**No**

RotD (page 4) on the Dragonblood subtype

> If a race possesses the dragonblood subtype, it has a strong affinity to dragons—which means that spells, effects, powers, and abilities that affect or target dragons also affect it. The subtype qualifies a creature to use magic items normally only usable by dragons, **and qualifies the creature to take feats that have the subtype as a prerequisite.** The dragonblood subtype also makes creatures subject to harmful effects that affect dragons.
>   The dragonblood subtype does not confer the dragon type or any traits associated with that type. For instance, it does not give a creature frightful presence. Dragons automatically qualify for any classes, prestige classes, racial substitution levels, feats, powers, or spells that require the dragonblood subtype. Races presented in this book that
>   have the dragonblood subtype include dragonborn, spellscale, kobold, and draconic creatures. Should a creature acquire the dragon type, it loses the dragonblood subtype.

The problem here is that Dragon is a type and Dragonblood is a subtype, so that sentence refers to being able to take feats with dragonblood prerequisite.

**With an arguable conflict**:

> Humanoid (dragonblood): Dragonborn are humanoids with the dragonblood subtype and any other subtypes they had before undergoing the Rite of Rebirth. For all effects related to race, a dragonborn is considered a dragon and a member of her original race.

Dragonborn defines Humanoid(dragonblood) as being a dragon and whatever they were before for *everything*. This should probably only apply to those who undergo the rite of rebirth (become dragonborn) however.

Comment: Dragonblood gives access to feats that require the dragonblood subtype. Not to feats (like those being asked about) that require the Dragon type.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I misread a reference to Dragonborn. I'll update

Comment: I don't think *requirements* count as *effects* really.

Comment: I'm starting to dislike whoever started using dragonborn and dragonblood interchangeably :-/
If spell A only affects dragons, there is a requirement that a target is a Dragon for it it have effects. ENworld has a thread about this topic, they were pretty split on whether it was possible or not. I think this is one that will come down to the DM time after time.

Comment: I don't think anyone does that..?

Comment: Just to throw in even more confusion. The sidebar on page 4 of the monster manual does the following:
"MONSTERS BY TYPE (AND SUBTYPE):
Dragon: dragons, dragon turtle, pseudodragon, wyvern."Which I'm pretty sure is wrong in all ways, since it is clearly not intending to say that psudodragon is a subtype of Dragon, but rather a type of the dragon type.

Comment: That's just a list of all creatures with the Dragon type present in the *Monster Manual*. It is not claiming that those are subtypes.